# Chrome (WINDOWS) missing cursor after an alert msg

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

In chrome (windows), I have a weird issue.

I prompt an alert after changing value in select dropdown.

When I click Ok, if I focus on 1 input text, I don't see blue border and no cursor.

In firefox, all is good. Any idea how to fix it? [here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22jscuud/)

[JS]

```
(function (){
    var focusing_val = "";
    $("#select").focus(function(){
        focusing_val = $(this).val();
    }).change(function (e) {
       console.log(focusing_val > 2);
       if ($(this).val() > 2) {
          e.preventDefault();
          alert("error");
          $(this).val(focusing_val);
          return false;
       }
   });
})();
```

[HTML]

```
<input type="text" value="123" />
<select name="test1" id="select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am using Chrome 44 on Linux and did not encounter this issue, so it might just be your machine.

Comment: This does in fact happen for me on Chrome 44.0.2403.155 m, windows. Changing tabs fixes it temporarily. Browser bug.

Comment: Im having the same issue (though it worked one time) on Chrome 44 Win

Comment: sorry guys, yes its on Windows (I have 44.0.2403.155 m)

Comment: ... they return upon leaving tab/page and re-focusing in the tab/page. Seems like a Chrome bug.

Comment: Related Chrome issue (other cause, same consequences): https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=465274

Comment: This is working for me on Chrome (Linux) Version 44.0.2403.125 (64-bit)  but it does not work correctly in Firefox (Linux) 39.0. In Firefox, if I choose 3, 4 or 5, it does not revert to what I had selected before, but the select does stay focused.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a setTimeout..

For me, it work..

```
(function (){
    var focusing_val = "";
    $("#select").focus(function(){
        focusing_val = $(this).val();
    }).change(function (e) {
       console.log(focusing_val > 2);
       if ($(this).val() > 2) {
          e.preventDefault();
          setTimeout(function() {
                alert("error");
          },0);
          $(this).val(focusing_val);
          return false;
       }
   });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I pretty sure this is a bug but I got it to work with this workaround that force the default styles to be reapplied to the input by focusing and bluring the input before calling the alert method, here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0vephn3L/), and here is the code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="123" id="input1" />
<select name="test1" id="select">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
(function (){
  var focusing_val = "";
  $("#select").focus(function(){
    focusing_val = $(this).val();
  }).change(function (e) {
    console.log(focusing_val > 2);
    if ($(this).val() > 2) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#input1').focus().blur();
      alert("error");
      $(this).val(focusing_val);
      return false;
    }
  });
})();
```